# Can't open SQLite Database but no clue why

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So this is my first shot at using a `sqlite` database with Android. I've tried a lot of things to make it work but it just won't open the d**n database.

The database `file` is in `res/assets`

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

From the log I know this much:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not  open database
```

This is the interesting part of the code:

```
    package de.minor.quizproto.database;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MinorDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private final Context myContext;

    public MinorDbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        this.myContext = context;
        DATABASE_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_FILE).getPath();
    }



    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "minor";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static String DATABASE_PATH;
    public static String DATABASE_FILE = "minor.db";

    private static final String TABLE_QUIZ = "quiz";
    private static final String TABLE_STATS = "stats";
    private static final String TABLE_FRIENDLIST = "friendlist";
    private static final String TABLE_FRIENDSTAT = "friendstat";

    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String QUESTION = "question";
    private static final String ANSWER1 = "answer1";
    private static final String ANSWER2 = "answer2";
    private static final String ANSWER3 = "answer3";
    private static final String ANSWER4 = "answer4";
    private static final String CORRECT = "correct";
    private static final String LEVEL = "level";
    private static final String QUIZ_ID = "quizid";
    private static final String TOPIC_ID = "topicid";

    private static final String TAG = "helper";


    //hoping copying the database helpwould help
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_FILE);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DATABASE_FILE;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }


    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH;
        Log.d("MinorDbHelper", myPath);

    //THAT'S THE LINE WHERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS:
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
```

The exception comes up in this line:

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Any idea what's going wrong? I've tried USB-Debugging and installing the apk - same result...

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Comment: can you show us your logCat ?

Comment: Where is create table query ? Have you created any tables ?

Comment: Refer this link http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: That's the log (part of it, it's rather long):

Comment: I have a database which already exists and isn't created programmatically. Does this work at all?

Comment: That's the log (part of it, it's rather long):03-27 15:35:37.415: E/AndroidRuntime(25965): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.minor.quizproto/de.minor.quizproto.GameActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change something here

```
 public String DB_PATH = "data/data/yourPkgNameHere/databases/"; // path

 public static String DB_NAME = "minor.db";// your database name
 static String ASSETS_DB_FOLDER = "db";


 public MinorDbHelper(Context context, String db_name) {
    super(context, db_name, null, 2);
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        close();

    this.myContext = context;
    DB_NAME = db_name;

    try {
        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // System.out.println("Exception in creation of database : "+
        // e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // System.out.println("Database Exist");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream input = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
    // System.out.println(DB_NAME + "Database Copied !");
}
```

Comment: this helped a great deal. thanx heaps

Answer (score 1):

Your code look quite ok in a first look. One weird stuff that I've observed is that you are creating your assets folder inside of res folder...That is maybe the reason why your code can not find/open the database. The assets folder has to be in the same level of src, res, bin, etc. folders. Try to move that folder and let see what happen when you call to

```
 myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_FILE);
```

Comment: In Eclipse it looks like my assets are same level as src, res etc.  From logging I get this path: /data/data/de.minor.quizproto/databases/minor.db  Is that the correct path?

Comment: the line you suggested works - no more Exception. But now I'm not sure how to refer to the database (NulllPointer...)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write database from assets to assets

```
 InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_FILE);
 String outFileName = DATABASE_FILE;
 OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
```

InputStream and OutputStream are pointing to the same location, it should probably be

```
 InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_FILE);
 OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DATABASE_PATH);
```